# Implicit declaration of function in spite of including header file

Tags: c, gcc, header, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings

I have a function `myfunc` defined in a source file `myfunc.c` and declared in a header file `myfunc.h`. Both these files are part of a library.

In another project's (projA) source file, I am including the header file as:

```
#include "myfunc.h"
```

and using the function correctly (number of parameters, order, etc).

I've edited the Makefile so it has the path to myfunc.h in it's list of includes (`-I`).

However, I am still getting a warning about implicit declaration. Since projA has warning = error set, it fails on compilation.

Note: this is not an eclipse issue as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11456338/c-implicit-declaration-differs-from-internal-function-declaration), or a missing header as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12127364/why-this-implicit-declaration-of-function-x), or an undeclared function.

**Addendum**

```
int myfunc(char * source, size_t source_len, char * dest, size_t dest_len)
{
    // manipulation
    strncpy(dest, source, dest_len);
    // other stuff
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your function?

Comment: Take a look at this http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Ifdef.html  You may need to add this in to your Header files

Comment: @EyeOfTheHawks thanks! Can you put your answer in the answer sections please? I will accept it. Someone decided to have the same MACRO for two different headers, and the one I wanted was not getting included. *Sigh*

Comment: @TonyTheLion adding the function declaration anyway...

Comment: @Sagar There ya go, added it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Ifdef.html
You may need to add this in to your Header files to avoid duplicate inclusion