# Implicit declaration of a function in spite of its inclusion in a header file

Tags: c, compilation, header, clion, c-strings

It's probably best to mention that I am running macOS for this and have found no issues on another Linux machine.

My project has a `master.h` file which includes a lot of headers which are used throughout the project. Here's a snippet:

```
#ifndef PROGETTOSO_MASTER_H
#define PROGETTOSO_MASTER_H

#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 199309L
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
```

Now, it seems like it works fine for all places but a particular function call in master.c

`printf("Signal: %s\n", strsignal(signum));` generates a warning (and thus an error) that `strsignal` is implicitly declared and when I try and run a quick fix via CLion on it, it simply places an include of `strings.h` at the **top of the file**, before the `master.h` include. That solves it, but I don't understand why, it's already included in master just like everything else there, why's the compiler having issues with it?

Also interestingly `strings.h` is not a listed requirement in the man page synopsis, `signal.h`  is and removing the strings include in favour of the signal one still solves the issue. Also works if I use only `string.h` as well.

So while this last bit is a little bit out of the question relevance, I thought I would still mention it, in any case, the include issue still stands.

I've tried looking at different SO questions (such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19938607/implicit-declaration-of-function-in-spite-of-including-header-file)), but haven't really managed to apply the answers to my codebase, or simply do not understand the situation I am in at the moment.

Comment: Does `master.h` have a final `#endif`?  I suggest you post enough of `master.c` to replicate the problem.

Comment: It does indeed, but that turned out not to be the issue as was explained in John's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your particular choice of feature test macros:

> ```
> #define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 199309L
> #define _GNU_SOURCE
> ```

`strsignal()` dates to the 2008 version of POSIX. Defining `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` as `199309L` specifically requests that `strsignal()` *not* be declared.  But that applies only to headers included *after* those macros are declared.

However, including one of the headers that (directly or indirectly) declares that function *before* the feature-test macros are defined can still get you a declaration of that function.  It can also get you inconsistency in which functions are declared and which not.

The correct solution is to use the correct feature test macros for the features you want.  In this case, you could try changing the `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` macro to

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
```

Comment: Thanks! That does seem to have been the issue, however, using the version you suggested now gives me tons of implicit declaration issues with `bzero`, which I previously used to just circumvent by declaring `strings.h` again in master.h.  I assume this is also still a macro issue considering that when I remove it altogether, the issues disappear and only `semtimedop` remains implicitly declared, which is a separate question I'll have to raise soon.

Comment: Scrap that - I've only just now seen that `bzero` is actually deprecated and `memset` should be used in its place. Thanks again!